# PDF file only displays on Samsung devices and not on iPhones when using ng2-pdf-viewer in an ionic with angular app

Tags: angular, typescript, ionic5, ng2-pdfjs-viewer, ng2-pdf-viewer

I am trying to preview a PDF file (using external URL) inside modal view component in an ionic with angular app, I am using ng2-pdf-viewer plugin. The PDF kdisplyed only on samsung device either after build ionic cordova to Android & IOS or using chrome inspect while the iphone device not disply the PDF file.

What I noted:

- the PDF displayed on page component on iphone device but not in modal view
- the PDF displyaed on modal view component on iphone device for a moments while refreshing the ionic app

can any one advice me please?

display PDF file using external URL in both Android & IOS device using ionic app